# rsyslogd RepeatedMsgReduction on a per-facility basis

Tags: rsyslog

I am using rsyslogd to remotely log certain facilities.  Repeated message reduction plays havok with the logserver filters, due to loss of information.

I see that I can disable $RepeatedMsgReduction globally in rsyslog, but I was hoping to disable it only on certain facilities, e.g. local*.  Is there a way to do that?